# Why use enum when #define is just as efficient?

Tags: c, enums

So an enum works like this:

```
enum {
  false,
  true
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
int false = 0
int true = 1
```

Why wouldn't I substitute `enum` with `#define`?

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
```

To me, it seems like they are interchangeable. I'm aware that `#define` is able to handle arguments, hence operates in an entirely different way than `enum`. What exactly are the main uses of `enum` when we have `#define` *in this case*?

If I were to guess, as the `#define` is a preprocessor feature, `enum` would have some runtime advantages. How far off am I?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136946/difference-between-enum-and-define-statements

Comment: Odd, that one didn't appear within my search results. Thanks!

Comment: It is not equivalent to `int false = 0` nor to `int const false = 0` (which would be more appropriate). `int` variables would have an address, you could then do `&false`, which you can't for an `enum`.

Comment: Note that [SO 136946](http://stackoverflow.com/q/136946/) is tagged with both C++ and C. Nominally, it is not as good a choice of duplicate as SO 1674032 which is for C only, but I could be persuaded otherwise.

Comment: It's funny that I found this question whilst wondering on exact the opposite: why are C programmers using `#defines`s instead of `enum`s.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The advantages of `enum` show up when you have a long list of things you want to map into numbers, and you want to be able to insert something in the middle of that list. For example, you have:

```
pears 0
apples 1
oranges 2
grapes 3
peaches 4
apricots 5
```

Now you want to put `tangerines` after `oranges`. With `#define`s, you'd have to redefine the numbers of `grapes`, `peaches`, and `apricots`. Using enum, it would happen automatically. Yes, this is a contrived example, but hopefully it gives you the idea.

Comment: Yes, I see the difference now. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer. **But assumes** the reader (who could be any NOOB) knows that she can declare an `enum` with `pears 0` and NOT number the rest.

Answer (score 19):

I find it useful for debugging in an environment such as gdb since enum values are handled at compile time (where #define is a preprocessor macro) and thus available for introspection.

Answer (score 6):

Although your question is tagged as C, there is a big advantage when writing in C++, you can place `enum:s` inside classes or namespaces.

This way you could refer to your constants like `SpaceshipClass::galaxy`.

Answer (score 0):

enum is an integer constant. so, there would be a type check during compilation process.

Comment: 0 and 1 are also integer constants.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it right Jim. I seem to have read about some implications of enum w.r.t. typecast and directly conveyed it without looking at the real question. The one other demarkation would be the use of enums in block scope.

Comment: In C++, enums are separate types, but not in C.