# Difference between using enum and int variables in C

Tags: c, enums, integer, int, constants

What is the difference between

```
enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};
enum week day = Wed;
```

and

```
enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};
int day = Wed;
```

in C?

I couldn't find what is the benefit of using variables of type `enum` over using a regular `int`.

Comment: ...    Readability    ...

Comment: `sizeof(enum week)` might be less than `sizeof(int)`. The C spec says that an enumerated type will be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. I suppose the compiler _could_ make the type wider than `int`, but since all the enumerated constants are type `int`, there is no need for it to be wider than `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The benefit is that using an `enum` make your intentions clearer, both to people reading your code and to the compiler. For example, any half-way decent compiler will warn you if you use an enum with incomplete `switch` cases:

```
switch (day) {
    case Mon: printf("Monday\n"); break;
    case Tue: printf("Tuesday\n"); break;
}
```

Here GCC (with `-Wall`) emits:

> warning: enumeration value 'Wed' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
>
> ```
> 7 |     switch (day) {
>   |     ^~~~~~
> ```
>
> …

If the type of `day` was `int`, you wouldn’t get this very helpful warning.

Comment: Maybe worth to note explicitly: This warning will only be thrown when the `default` case is omitted, but not when not.

Answer (score 2):

The identifiers/constants of the `enum` have type `int`, so it is permissible to assign the values of them to `int` variables:

> "The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int` and may appear wherever such are permitted."
>
> C18, §6.7.7.2/3

However, the type of the enumeration can vary per implementation:

> "Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type.  The choice of type is implementation-defined,131) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration."
>
> C18, §6.7.7.2/4

So, sticking with `enum` type might prevent any kind of type issues when dealing with `enum`s beside being more readable.

---

Another thing is that it is easily possible to assign the constant of another `enum` type to `day`, if it has type `int`.

```
enum week {Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};
enum month {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dez};

int day = Mar;
```

This compiles with no issues.

A high-leveled compiler *can* throw a warning for this when using type `enum week` for `day` instead and adds with this an extra layer of security.

```
enum week {Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};
enum month {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec};

enum week day = Mar;
```

For example, Clang, 10.0 throws without any additional flag:

> "*warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum month' to different enumeration type 'enum week' [-Wenum-conversion]*"

GCC, 10.1 needs the `-Wall` or `-Wenum-conversion` flag to emit the same warning.

---

Also this post covers a similar concern, but I wouldn't go so far as declaring it as duplicate:

- [Is there no problem using enumeration without declaration of enum variable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017336)

Furthermore, I've found this interesting article:

- https://www.embedded.com/enumerations-are-integers-except-when-theyre-not/

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations in C are a convenient way to create symbolic constants for small sets of things that aren't necessarily ordered.

They're not a *high-level* abstraction in C the way they are in Java or C#.  They're integer types under the hood, and because C trusts that *you know what you're doing at all times and never, ever make a mistake* it doesn't complain when you mix and match `enum` and `int` types.