# Why would I use enum as a type?

Tags: c, enums

I saw a [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921557/14189755) about using boolean types in C. One of the answers listed four ways to implement boolean types, the second and third way being:

```c
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

and

```c
typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };
```

The first one confused me at first because I had never seen an `enum` being used as a type. Since `enum` defines integer constants, I thought it was the same thing as the second one but slightly more confusing.

So, how does using `enum` as a type work? Is there a difference between using `enum` as a type and using an integer type, defining the `enum` elsewhere? Most importantly, why would someone use `enum` as a type?

Comment: Every `enum` is a type. Maybe you are confused by the fact that you can implicitly convert an integer to an `enum` value?

Comment: Maybe the second answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249307/difference-between-using-enum-and-int-variables-in-c) can help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the first example is confusing. It's more clear than the second one. It's saying there is a type, called `bool`, and it has two possible values: `true` and `false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between using enum and int variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249307/difference-between-using-enum-and-int-variables-in-c)

Comment: The “why” appears answered in the linked question. If the focus was on comparing the differences (if any) between the two forms shown in the question, then consider making that the focus in question *and* title.

Comment: Enums as types in C are kind of half-assed. Because they're "compatible with an integer type" (even worse than being weakly convertible to/from integers), you can't really use them to force limit their value to one of the enumerated constants. For me, the only (nonportable) thing they've got going for them is that gcc and clang autosuggest case labels if you use an enum-typed variable as the controlling expression of a switch.

Comment: @Botahamec I think the first one is cleaner, I just want to understand it before I start using it. The second one merely conforms more to my previous understanding of enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in programming, `enums` are used for creating lists of defined final values. And because `booleans` can be either `true` or `false`, it is a good fit to implement it this way.

The first code bit you included is quite simple, it defines a type called `bool` as an `enum` that can be either `true` or `false`. Why it's defined here in the enum is because this way you won't get an error, when using `true`/`false` as values in your code. Also, there's a reason, why `false` is listed first - on the index 0 and `true` is on the index 1. Can you guess? ...You can convert `enum` element to `int` by its index (meaning: this way when you work with `false` value, you are basically working with 0).

The second code is very similar, it defines type `bool`, but as an `integer` instead. That's because that's how you normally represent `bools` in C = 1 (or any other int to get `true`) or 0 (`false`). The definition of `enum` here is again just to prevent from getting an error, when using `true` and `false` as values. Again the values are positioned this way for a reason - thanks to which you can just do `if (true)` or `if (false)` and it will work as intended (the reason is described above).