# What's the purpose of defining a C macro to be itself? (seen in glibc headers)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

On an Ubuntu Linux 20.04 machine, in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/resource.h`, I see code like this:

```
enum __rusage_who
{
  /* The calling process.  */
  RUSAGE_SELF = 0,
#define RUSAGE_SELF RUSAGE_SELF

  /* All of its terminated child processes.  */
  RUSAGE_CHILDREN = -1
#define RUSAGE_CHILDREN RUSAGE_CHILDREN
};
```

We see that `RUSAGE_SELF` is defined to be itself. What is the purpose/benefit of it?

[image]

Comment: It might be needed so that `#ifdef RUSAGE_SELF` will work.

Comment: @Barmar But wouldn't `#define RUSAGE_SELF` be enough then?

Comment: But then it won't have a valuie.

Comment: You might want, e.g. `#define RUSAGE_SELF RUSAGE_OTHER`

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: My image is a bonus, to make it distinguishable from other similar questions. No critical information regarding the question is hidden in the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in the comment in the same file.

```
/* Transmute defines to enumerations.  The macro re-definitions are
   necessary because some programs want to test for operating system
   features with #ifdef RUSAGE_SELF.  In ISO C the reflexive
   definition is a no-op.  */
```

So they are just for feature testing with `#ifdef` to work.

You also want them to be actually usable as (compile-time) integral constant expressions. So `#define RUSAGE_SELF` will not work, you have to do `#define RUSAGE_SELF RUSAGE_SELF`.

The first sentence of the above comment indicates that it is very likely it was originally just
`#define RUSAGE_SELF 0`.
Indeed, for example [this link](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/linux/resource.h.html) contains the line `#define RUSAGE_SELF 0`.

However, although borderline opinion-based, defining integral constants as macros is inferior to using an enum for various reasons. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243269/why-use-enum-when-define-is-just-as-efficient) for details. As they need to be macros for feature testing with `#ifdef`, and after they decided to make the transition and rewrite them as enums, they need to ensure that those code are not broken by the change.

From the [man page of getrusage(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html), I can imagine someone may write the following code in order to be portable,

```
#ifdef RUSAGE_THREAD
if(getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, usage)==0){
    //Do something
}
else{
    //Error handling
}
#endif
```

This is necessary because `RUSAGE_THREAD` is only available in Linux >= 2.6.26. The only two choices that can make the above compile are

```
#define RUSAGE_THREAD 1
```

and

```
enum __rusage_who{
    //...
    RUSAGE_THREAD = 1;
#define RUSAGE_THREAD RUSAGE_THREAD
};
```

Since it has been decided that the latter is used, for the sake of consistency it makes sense to do the same for the other constants, including `RUSAGE_SELF` and `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`, although those two are guaranteed to be valid under POSIX.