# Why #defines instead of enums

Tags: c, enums, constants, c-preprocessor

Here I am thinking ... 
Why do I see much more often the use of `#define` instead of `enum` in other people's code when defining error codes for the return value of functions? 
Is there a reason for this, or is it just a matter of taste?
As far as I know, enums are much more safer and debugger friendlier.

Comment: Here are some C duplicates: [#define or enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3134757/3425536) / [What makes a better constant in C, a macro or an enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17125505/3425536) / [Why use enum when #define is just as efficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5243269/3425536)